# React state vs variable vs function call

Tags: reactjs, dom, use-state, react-functional-component, rerender

This is my project:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);
  const by2 = !(number%2)
  const by3 = !(number%3)
  const by5 = !(number%5)
  const by7 = !(number%7)
  const by11 = !(number%11)

  return(
    <>
      {by2 && <div>Divisible by 2</div>}
      {by3 && <div>Divisible by 3</div>}
      {by5 && <div>Divisible by 5</div>}
      {by7 && <div>Divisible by 7</div>}
      {by11 && <div>Divisible by 11</div>}
      <button onClick={() => setNumber(prev => prev +1)}>click me</button>
    </>
  )
}
export default Component
```

I want it to do this: Given the initial state

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);
```

and the button that increments it

```
<button onClick={() => setNumber(prev => prev +1)}>click me</button>
```

the other 5 components should only appear if their conditions are true.

```
  const by2 = !(number%2)
  const by3 = !(number%3)
  const by5 = !(number%5)
  const by7 = !(number%7)
  const by11 = !(number%11)
```

The thing is, this works! The logic I did in by2, by3, by5, etc... works just like I wanted. But at the same time I thought: When is it okay to use variables or function calls inside a component? I had some issues in the past, in which variables didn't update their values in re-renders like I wanted them to. So I felt like I should use states, or even function calls like this:

```
  const by2 = () => !(number%2)
  const by3 = () => !(number%3)
  const by5 = () => !(number%5)
  const by7 = () => !(number%7)
  const by11 = () => !(number%11)

  {by2() && <div>Divisible by 2</div>}
  {by3() && <div>Divisible by 3</div>}
  {by5() && <div>Divisible by 5</div>}
  {by7() && <div>Divisible by 7</div>}
  {by11() && <div>Divisible by 11</div>}
```

So what I'd like to know is, what is the impact of choosing these 3 approches? In which case can I use variables instead of states, and are function calls without a parameter the same as using a variable in this case?

Comment: if you want to understand more about scope, I recommend [You Don't Know JS Yet: Scope & Closures](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/ch1.md) ... and the [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) from the official documentation is very helpful for determining whether you need state and where it should live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this simple example both the approaches will be similar. They do not have much of a difference.

But if you define functions whenever the state gets updated the functions will be redefined which is not intended. You might face issues when you are using the functions as prop to child component. Because these functions will be redefined on each render this might trigger re-render of child as well which might not be desired in all the cases. In order to avoid this we use `useCallback`, `useMemo` and `React.Memo` etc.

Since all your variables are dependant on state so whenever the state gets updated  variables will also get updated. So for your requirement defining variables suits well.

> In which case can I use variables instead of states

- You define only those objects/values as just variables when you doesn't want the component to get re-rendered upon updating the value.
- Define all those objects/values as state when you wish to re-render the component on the value change/update like `number` in this example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't get the first thing that you said. Why would I face an issue if my function definition changed? This seems exactly what I wanted, because in a future re-render I would want another value when executing by2(), so what's the issue?  
And what causes the re-render on a child element is the state isn't it? Why would the function or a variable be the problem?

Comment: Consider, if you are passing one of these functions as a prop to a child and the same prop is used as a dependency for `useEffect` in the child. Then when this Parent component gets re-rendered because of state change the function will be redefined and the function reference will get changed which will trigger the child component `useEffect` that might not be expected. This is where we use `useCallback` or `useMemo` or `React.Memo` depending on the use case

Comment: For more info please refer [this](https://medium.com/@jan.hesters/usecallback-vs-usememo-c23ad1dc60) about the problem I'm talking about and also about the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely say that in this simple case, it's the same if you use variables or function calls. When calling `setNumber`, you are re-rendering your component and the variables should update correctly.

Maybe in your last project where you said that the variables weren't updating there was something else...